# mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() issue during onPause() event

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

I have implemented seekber and mediaplayer but application crashed during onPause() event, my section on code that cause issue:

```
updateSeekBar = new Thread( ){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int totalduration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        int currentPosition = 0;               
        while(currentPosition < totalduration && !isOnPause){
            try {
                Message message =  new Message();
                message.what = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                handler.sendMessage(message);
                sleep(500);
                currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                positionBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

The error:

```
04-16 19:54:11.298 24488-24527/com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
Process: com.xxxxxxx.xxxxx, PID: 24488
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
    at com.soleofficiel.happykiosk.NewOneMusicPlayer$1.run(NewOneMusicPlayer.java:79)
```